# Почему "елейный" синоним "приторного"?

Tags: синонимы

Может, у меня глупый вопрос, но мне всегда было не понятно, почему слово "елейный" является синонимом слова "приторный"? Елей - это оливковое масло. Думаю, оливковое масло пробовали все и знают, что оно практически безвкусное. И запах у него совсем не сильный. При чем же тут приторность?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Елейный" является синонимом слова "приторный" не в прямом смысле, а в переносном - приторно-ласковый, слащавый,умильный, угодливый, ханжески ласковый. Елейное выражение лица = масляно-слащавое.

Здесь соотносится с двумя значениями - масло (елейное)и церковность(елей и ладан как приобщение к святым таинствам.)
Елей — это оливковое масло, освященное на мощах православных святых, которые при жизни занимались исцелением людей. Елеосвящение - это  помазание елеем на челе, ноздрях, ланитах, устах, персях, горле, руках с обеих сторон, за ушами.
Елей — образ милости Божьей, любви и сострадания. Кроме исцеления от болезней елеосвящение дарует  прощение забытых грехов. Помазанный имеет вид благостный,блаженный, с масляной улыбкой и елейным выражением лица от сошедшей на него благодати. Отсюда и такое выражение - елейное. А отойдёт чуть - и заново грешить. Или вид-то такой, а сам думает о корысти - ханжество, елейность.

Comment: Чудесное объяснение!